# adding a shared_ptr object on a weak_ptr container

Tags: boost, server, client, smart-pointers

My class is based on boost::asio tutorial.

This class has a private ctor, is derived from enable_shared_from_this.

its static member function return a shared_ptr from the object created.

I want to store those pointers on a list of weak_ptr, so the list don't need to worry about its life time, either prolong it.

The caller tcp_serve instantiate tcp_connection with create method:

tcp_server:

```
        tcp_connection::pointer new_connection =
    tcp_connection::create(acceptor_.get_io_service());
```

tcp_connection:

```
PUBLIC:
typedef boost::shared_ptr<tcp_connection> pointer;

static pointer create(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
{
    return pointer(new tcp_connection(io_service));
}

PRIVATE:
tcp_connection(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
: _socket(io_service), _timer(io_service)
{
}
```

I am trying to create a list on the tcp_server, I tried many different kind of types, but I can't rightly added the object to the list:

```
    std::list<std::weak_ptr<tcp_connection>> connections;
    connections.push_back(new_connection);
```

Comment: You can't mix std smart_ptrs and boost smart_ptrs.

Comment: Wow, I didn't notice it. Even if I fix both types, how would I write the list template, and the push_back argument properly? Or should I add a function to tcp_connection, adding "shared_from_this()" to a weak_point list?

Comment: The list and the push back looks correct _if you choose to use std pointers_. Otherwise, It would be `std::list<boost::weak_ptr<tcp_connection>>`. They should work equally good, I prefer std's smart_ptr's though as one dependency less is always good.

Comment: You were right, everything is now working properly. I have changed all the boost shared, and now using std memory. Thanks for your help.